# EM effects within a semi-conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, semiconductor-physics

I have overviewed a number of semi-conductor physics texts and none seem to factor in the effects of radiation, induction, etc into their account of semi-conductor internals.

Why can these effects be essentially ignored and still produce correct results? Given the highspeed nature these devices are operating at (some in the 100ghz range) it seems like these effects would start to play a significant role in the devices behavior.

Comment: You perhaps should do some back of the envelope estimated of how much, say, induction impacts transistor operation (hint, no loops of current). Then, what kind of radiation?

Answer (score 1):

Internal capacitance does play a significant role in limiting the performance of high speed devices like transistors.

It can also be a useful [diagnostic tool (Capacitance spectroscopy)](http://www.nanobionics.pro.br/capacitance-spectroscopy-and-electrochemical-capacitance)

Inductance plays a central role in the [Hall effect](https://electricalfundablog.com/hall-effect-principle-history-theory-explanation-mathematical-expressions-applications/).

As for radiation effects. There is a huge volume of literature and devices that rely on the interaction of semiconductors with light: solar cells, LEDs, photodetector, lasers.